# Image/Basis Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Given the three dimension space $x + 2y + 3z + 4t = 0$, write the plane as the image of a 4x3 matrix and find a basis for this space.

We get $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$ $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ t \end{bmatrix}$ = $x+2y+3z+4t$. Afterwards, we can find three unique solutions to the equation taht could suffice as our matrix: take {1, 1, -1, 0}, {0, 3, -2, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 3}. 
However, I don't really know how to move on from there. Any help?

Comment: Those vectors will be the columns of the matrix, after you have corrected the mistake in one of them.

Comment: @David Then how to do I find the basis?

Comment: Do you know how many vectors you need for a basis in this case?

Comment: @David nope, unfortunately

Comment: Suggest you read about [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)).

Comment: @Derek Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 0):

The three vectors you find (with a correction in the third)  $$\{1, 1, -1, 0\}, \{0, 3, -2, 0\}, \{0, 0, 4, -3\}$$ satisfy the plane equation and are linearly independent, since the plane has dimension 3 those vectors are a basis for the subspace/plane, thus the matrix we are looking for is

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 0\\
-1 & -2 & 4\\
0 & 0 & -3\end{bmatrix}$$